RGB LED audio meter
I'm planning to build an audio meter using ATmega328 chip and 2 RGB LEDs for both stereo channels. The color of an LED will be dependent on the level of the signal flowing to chips ADC.
I'm also planning to do it on a custom PCB without using pre-built circuit boards like the Arduino Nano etc. My method of programming the chip will be ISP programmer.
I wonder about some things.
First: ATmega328 has 6 PWM outputs, so that's exactly what I need, but to program the chip via ISP I need to share one pin of LED with one pin of ISP programmer. Can I leave it like this sharing the microcontroller pin or it will be wiser to include a jumper to disconnect the LED?
Second: Is driving LEDs from microcontroller pins sufficient? Maybe it will be better to use transistors to amplify the drive current? If yes, can you please recommend me some circuits?
Last thing is just a simple question - am I missing something here? The circuit is included below. Is it good to go?


What drives the meter inputs? An audio input connector directly?

No, there is a buffer with a half wave rectifier before.

the ISP uses the Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) which is not used by the analog pins but rather by the digital pins (10-13). So you dont need to use any jumpers. Correct me if I am wrong.


You don't know the drive ability of the programmer. It might be able to drive the pin with the LED or not. Having said that, with your 3.3 kohm resistor, the current of the LED will be extremely small, which may be a good thing for the programming, but also the LED likely won't be very bright, and you might want a brighter LED.

As said, the LED currents are quite low so the MCU can drive the small load. But you might want more current for brighter LEDs. Each pin has a rated condition of 20mA at 5V or 10mA at 3V, but the blue LED likely needs more than 3V already. Pins can drive more current, but there are also limits for total current per pin groups, which could be 100mA, and there are also maximum ratings per pin and per total supplied. If all your LEDs are 20mA and they are synchronized to same timer phase, at 50% PWM they all 6 may consume total of 120mA and 0mA if they are not staggered. You may want to use buffers or transistors for driving to use more current and offload it from MCU, but also, just BJTs will make things complicated as they are slow to turn off unless you make some more effort that put just a base resistor.

If the voltages from audio circuit are only positive it should work. There is power, bypassing, clock and programmig circuit, even with ESD protection. However not knowing the supply voltage or exact crystal type it is hard to say if they are compatible. The VREF pin is floating, you might want to do something with it, as you might not want to spend the 10-bit ADC to 5V full scale, the VREF could also be something lower from a precision reference.




I will use a jumper then and disconnect the led for programming.
I was thinking about N-MOSFETs, i think they will work well with PWM modulation.
I use half wave rectifier so voltages are only positive. Regarding VREF - if i want to use full scale from 0V to 5V should i leave this pin floating?


You could see the data sheet how to best handle AREF. Sometimes for best results you need a capacitor there. It's just the parts that you don't show that can be problematic - there is no half-wave audio rectifier, and there is no schematics to see if it works as raw waveform buffer or peak detector or how.
